# Using input outside Modal's container

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap

I'm currently working with a modal that has a specific container. I also have an input component that is located outside of the modal. My goal is to be able to use (or interact with) this input component when the modal is open, but I'm encountering an issue where the input component cannot be focused. I need assistance to resolve this problem.

Link for this issue: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bootstrap-modal-container-forked-7hlx93)

[Input and Modal with specific container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baDcY.png)

I'm try to change Modal's props and fix container but nothing works.
Note: Offcanvas of react-bootstrap works normally

Comment: try to describe your issue more specifically.
what had you try, why it won't work.